# Programatically Update XAML Data Template in Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a data template like so:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemTmpl">
        <Grid Margin="6">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Height="90" Width="90" Background="#eee" />

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I am setting a List View Item Source in the code behind like so:

```
lv.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["itemTmpl"];
```

How can I programatically change the Border Background before the template gets rendered to my UI?

Comment: Does it(background) depend on the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a few things:

- Parse the Visual Tree (using a VisualTreeHelper or extension method such as from [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://codeplex.winrtxamltoolkit.com/)), find the border (likely by its `x:Name`) and set the Background.
- Bind the Background to a value in your Item
- Bind the Background to a value in your VM

For any of the two Bindings, you can use a Converter to convert from a non-brush value to the proper brush value (such as if you wanted it to change colors based on if it were Checked, a `bool`, or not).

For the second binding, make sure that you set the Source to your VM, as the DataContext will be, by default, your Item. Also, make sure that your Item inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged so that your Bindings will get updated based on the changes in data properly.

Comment: Interesting really thanks for the response. It's unfortunate there isn't an easy way to do accomplish this. However the VM approach makes some sense. I just hate polluting my POCO data models you know?

Comment: Is there an easy way to Parse the Visual Tree without bringing in a dependency?

Comment: Recurse through the visual tree using the [VisualTreeHelper.GetChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper). You can create a helper method and use it all over.